# How to uninstall ODBC datasource with Batch or VBS?

Tags: vbscript, odbc, uninstallation

I need to uninstall an ODBC data source on ~30 computers and was hoping there'd be a quicker way than using the ODBC Administration GUI. This is a one time deal so I'm hoping to use a VBS or a Batch file. I've tried using `reg delete` but the data source still hows up in the ODBC Administration GUI.

Anyone know how to uninstall an ODBC data source with a VBS or a Batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, but it's not very neat because you'll have to edit the registry directly. To be more specific, your DSNs (or at least the System ones which are the only ones I've used) are stored in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI`, both as a subdirectory and as a single key under the `ODBC Data Sources` sub directory.

This Technet article should give you all the technical details: [Can I Create and Delete a DSN Using a Script?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/11/10/can-i-create-and-delete-a-dsn-using-a-script.aspx)

In general, if you need to do something via scripting, the [Scripting Guy Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/) is a good place to look for information.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed that article. Apparently I was missing the `ODBC Data Sources` key.

Answer (score 0):

I do this, but what makes it easy is using "file DSNs" instead of System or User DSNs.  Then I only have to delete the file to get rid of the connection.

Here rough draft on how to do a File DSN in a batch file.  The key is that in your ODBC properties file, you use FILEDSN=  instead of DSN= as a parameter to the driver:

```
SET fileobject=Tools\T4e\t4esql.exe
:loop
 CALL :GETDIR "%dir%"
 IF EXIST "%dir%\%fileobject%" (
   ECHO Directory containing object %fileobject% is %dir%>>forcePasswordReset.bat.log
   GOTO :FOUND
 )
 IF "%dir:~-1%" == ":" (
   ECHO Directory containing "%fileobject%" not found!!!!!>>forcePasswordReset.bat.log
   GOTO :FOUND
 )
GOTO loop
:FOUND
if not exist mssql.dsn (
  ECHO MSSQL DSN not found>>forcePasswordReset.bat.log
  CALL :MSSQLDSN
)
:: test database connectivity
:: test user for uniqueness in database ELSE fail script
echo SELECT COUNT(user_login) FROM Users WHERE user_login='%USERNAME%';>>feset.bat.log
%dir%\%fileobject% -d:"FILEDSN=%CD%\mssql.dsn" -q:"SELECT COUNT(user_login) FROM Users WHERE user_login='%USERNAME%';" -o:%CD%\count.res noheaders nostats
set /P CNT=< %CD%\count.res
echo This user was found in the database %CNT% times.>>feset.bat.log
GOTO :END
:MSSQLDSN
SET /P MDB=What is the MSSQL database name? 
if "%MDB%"=="" (
  ECHO You need to type a MSSQL database name on the local SQL instance.  
  ECHO If you get it wrong, delete the .dsn file and try this script again.
  ECHO.
  GOTO MSSQLDSN
)
:MSSQLDSN
@echo [ODBC]> mssql.dsn
@echo DRIVER=SQL Server>> mssql.dsn
@echo UID=%USERNAME%>> mssql.dsn
@echo Trusted_Connection=Yes>> mssql.dsn
@echo DATABASE=%MDB%>> mssql.dsn
@echo WSID=%COMPUTERNAME%>> mssql.dsn
@echo APP=Microsoft Data ACCESS Components>> mssql.dsn
@echo SERVER=(local)>> mssql.dsn
@echo Description=Local SQL Instance>> mssql.dsn
@echo. >> mssql.dsn
GOTO :EOF
:GETDIR
SET "dir=%~dp1"
SET "dir=%dir:~0,-1%"
::echo %dir%
GOTO :EOF
:END
pause
```